# Open XML parts are missing in dynamically created Word document

Tags: c#, openxml, libreoffice

I'm creating `WordprocessingDocument`s in C# with the Open XML SDK and then converting them to pdf. Initially, I was using Interop to save the document in PDF format, but now that is not an option. I found that LibreOffice can convert documents calling soffice.exe from cmd, and I had wonderful results with normal documents. Still, then, when I tested LibreOffice converter with my dynamic documents, the converter crashed.

I copied one of these documents and opened it with LibreOffice Writer, its structure was wrong, then I opened the same document with Microsoft Word and its structure was fine. Finally, I saved it with Microsoft Word and opened both documents as ZIP files as below:

This is the good one:

[image: Good document structure]

And this is the bad one:

[image: Bad document structure]

I noticed that when I save the document in Microsoft Word, these Open XML parts (which I called "files" in an earlier version of this question) are appearing. When I open the document previously saved with Microsoft Word in LibreOffice, the document is fine again.

Thus, is there a way to generate these Open XML parts (inside the Word document) without opening Microsoft Word?

I use the following code (to check if it is creating all the files):

```
        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Create Document
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
            {
                // Add a main document part. 
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                // Create the document structure and add some text.
                mainPart.Document = new Document();
                Body docBody = new Body();

                // Add your docx content here
                CreateParagraph(docBody);
                CreateStyledParagraph(docBody);
                CreateTable(docBody);
                CreateList(docBody);

                Paragraph pImg = new Paragraph();
                ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
                string imgPath = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/11/15/05/23/dog-4627679_960_720.png";
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imgPath);
                req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                req.PreAuthenticate = true;
                req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                imagePart.FeedData(resp.GetResponseStream());

                // 1500000 and 1092000 are img width and height
                Run rImg = new Run(DrawingManager(mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), "PictureName", 1500000, 1092000, string.Empty));
                pImg.Append(rImg);
                docBody.Append(pImg);

                Paragraph pLink = new Paragraph();
                // For the mainpart see above
                pLink.Append(HyperLinkManager("http://YourLink", "My awesome link", mainPart));
                docBody.Append(pLink);

                mainPart.Document.Append(docBody);
                mainPart.Document.Save();
                wordDocument.Close();
            }

            result = Convert.ToBase64String(mem.ToArray());
        }
```

The code above creates a Word document named Result.docx with the following structure:

[image: Result.docx structure]

But there aren't any other Open XML parts (like `app.xml` or `styles.xml`)

Comment: This question is not programming related, and therefore isn't appropriate to ask here. You're looking for [su] instead.

Comment: Since these are docx, Word's native file format, Word is designed to be able to work with the "bare bones" and supplement what's missing. There *might* be another software, out there, that can handle missing content in a similar way, I don't know. But either you need to write a program that does what you need (using the Open XML SDK, for example), find such a software (which question is off-topic on Stack Overflow) or open the "partial" documents in Word. If you have access to SharePoint on-premise Word Automation Services should be able to handle it, as well as convert to PDF.

Comment: Can you share a minimum reproducible example of how you create those Word documents? It sounds like there are issues with the Open XML markup you create. Word might just be more forgiving than LibreOffice. Further, Word will produce its own Open XML markup when it saves a document and the markup created by Word will include parts that you did not initially create (e.g., app.xml, core.xml, styles.xml).

Comment: Just added the sample code and the results from it. Please check it :D

Comment: @LuisBarajas, I edited your question to improve the terminology, e.g., because your "files" are actually "parts". Based on your sample code and the package contents of your Word document, I provided an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a difference between:

- the Open XML standard and its minimum requirements on a `WordprocessingDocument` and
- the "minimum" document created by Microsoft Word or other applications.

As per the standard, the minimum `WordprocessingDocument` only needs a main document part (`MainDocumentPart`, `document.xml`) with the following content:

```xml
<w:document xmlns:w="...">
  <w:body>
    <w:p />
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Further parts such as the `StyleDefinitionsPart` (`styles.xml`) or the `NumberingDefintionsPart` (`numbering.xml`) are only required if you have styles or numbering, in which case you must explicitly create them in your code.

Next, looking at your sample code, it seems you are creating:

1. paragraphs that reference styles (see `CreateStyledParagraph(docBody)`), which would have to be defined in the `StyleDefinitionsPart` (`styles.xml`); and
2. numbered lists (e.g., `CreateList(docBody)`), which would have to be defined in the `NumberingDefinitionsPart` (`numbering.xml`).

However, your code neither creates a `StyleDefinitionsPart` nor a `NumberingDefintionsPart`, which means your document is likely not a valid Open XML document.

Now, Word is very forgiving and fixes various issues silently, ignoring parts of your Open XML markup (e.g., the styles you might have assigned to your paragraphs).

By contrast, depending on how fault-tolerant LibreOffice is, invalid Open XML markup might lead to a crash. For example, if LibreOffice simply assumes that a `StyleDefinitionsPart` exists when it finds an element like `<w:pStyle w:val="MyStyleName" />` in your `w:document` and then does not check whether it gets a `null` reference when asking for the `StyleDefinitionsPart`, it could crash.

Finally, to add parts to your Word document, you would use the Open XML SDK as follows:

```cs
[Fact]
public void CanAddParts()
{
    const string path = "Document.docx";
    const WordprocessingDocumentType type = WordprocessingDocumentType.Document;

    using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(path, type);

    // Create minimum main document part.
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(new Body(new Paragraph()));

    // Create empty style definitions part.
    var styleDefinitionsPart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<StyleDefinitionsPart>();
    styleDefinitionsPart.Styles = new Styles();

    // Create empty numbering definitions part.
    var numberingDefinitionsPart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<NumberingDefinitionsPart>();
    numberingDefinitionsPart.Numbering = new Numbering();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation, i've tried it and it works :) the dynamic documents are fine now :D